# Qt 6.4.1, no Qt6Multimedia folder present - CMakeLists.txt can't find the module

Tags: qt, cmake, module, qt6

I am using Qt 6.4.1, and in QtCreator I am trying to import the Qt6 Multimedia module, but I get the following error:

[image]

The error says **"Found package configuration file: C:/Qt/qt/6.4.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT FOUND. Reason given by package: Failed to find required Qt component "Multimedia". Expected config file at "C:/Qt/qt/6.4.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Multimedia/Qt6MultimediaConfig.cmake" does NOT exist"**

It appears my Qt version does not have the folder in my cmake directory:

[image]

Why is this? Have I missed something/got something wrong or is there no support for the Multimedia module in Qt6.4.1? What can I do to import this module? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The multimedia module is an add-on module; you may need to install it separately, that is, if it's available for mingw at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check QtMultimedia in QtMaintenanceTool when you are installing Qt. See the screenshot:

[image]

If it is not available for your compiler, then you have no other option than build Qt with QtMultimedia on your own.