# Missing Module QtHttpServer

Tags: c++, rest, qt, cmake

I want to connect to a RESTful API with Qt6. Searching on the Internet i found this article on the Web explaining that i could use QtHttpServer for this purpose.

But as i try to use this module it appears that it is missing on my Qt installation.
here is the Error message i received:

`D:\git\TestIt\CMakeLists.txt:9: error: Found package configuration file: C:/Qt/6.2.4/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package: Failed to find Qt component "HttpServer". Expected Config file at "C:/Qt/6.2.4/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake/Qt6HttpServer/Qt6HttpServerConfig.cmake" does NOT exist`

The thing is, this is true. I checked the path `C:/Qt/6.2.4/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake/Qt6HttpServer/Qt6HttpServerConfig.cmake` and there is no `Qt6HttpServer` folder.

So i checked if i missed anything in the QtMaintenence program to make sure i did not miss to add it to my Qt installation. But i found nothing that i could add.

I also checked if i need to download this somewhere but i only found the documentation site here: `https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthttpserver-index.html` aslo not mentioning how to get this module.

So my Question is, how can i fix this and get the module?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer because of a related question here on stackoverflow.
The reason for this is, i am using Qt `6.2.4` and the Qt Html Server is available earliest at `6.4.3` Version of Qt.

So i need to upgrade my Qt Version to `6.4.3` using Qt Maintenence Tool and then it will be available.

Related Question: [Qt 6.4.1, no Qt6Multimedia folder present - CMakeLists.txt can't find the module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74990754/qt-6-4-1-no-qt6multimedia-folder-present-cmakelists-txt-cant-find-the-module?rq=2)